# View overlap Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am trying do transparent toolbar that has to overlap other view. But conversely other view overlap toolbar.

[image]

In xml I specially used margintop for RelativeLayout that show overlapping. Actually I don't use marginTop for RelativeLayout.

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".activity.activitys.ActivityImage">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/action_bar_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Фото"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/img_slideshow_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/img_border"
        >
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
        <kz.dreamwings.zhaksyadam.activity.util.CircleIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:background="#99000000"
            android:layout_above="@+id/img_name"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: try - android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" in your relative layout (i.e. img_slideshow_layout) and also remove margintop attribute from the same

Comment: use LinearLayout instead of FrameLayout  and every thing will be fine

Answer (score 1):

You are using `FrameLayout` which is basically for holding a single child. You cant manage the alignment of childrens in `FrameLayout`.
Your layout should be like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/action_bar_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Фото" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/img_slideshow_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/img_border">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <kz.dreamwings.zhaksyadam.activity.util.CircleIndicator
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/img_name"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="#99000000"
                android:padding="3dip" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/img_border"
    tools:context=".activity.activitys.ActivityImage">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/action_bar_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Фото"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/img_slideshow_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        .
        .
        .
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: add toolbar after relative layout and remove top margin .
.i.e:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".activity.activitys.ActivityImage">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/img_slideshow_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/img_border"
        >
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
        <kz.dreamwings.zhaksyadam.activity.util.CircleIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:background="#99000000"
            android:layout_above="@+id/img_name"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/action_bar_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Фото"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</FrameLayout>
```